# Assign objects to an object

Tags: java

I have been given this as part of an assignment:

```
private static void addStudent(int id, String firstName, String lastName,int 
mathsMark1, int mathsMark2, int mathsMark3, int englishMark1, int 
englishMark2, 
int englishMark3)
```

with the explanation:

Creates a new Student object and two AsignmentMarks objects (for Mathematics and English). Assign the values of these three objects using the parameters given. Remember to assign the two AssignmentMarks objects to the Student object. Finally, adds the Student to the list of students.

student class:

```
public class Student {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public AssignmentMarks mathMarks;
    public AssignmentMarks englishMarks;

    public Student(int studentID, String firstName, String lastName, int 
    mathMark1, int mathMark2, int mathMark3, int englishMark1, int englishMark2, 
    int englishMark3) {

        id = studentID;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;

    }
}
```

Assignment Marks class:

```
public class AssignmentMarks {

    private String courseName;
    private int assignment1;
    private int assignment2;
    private int assignment3;

    public AssignmentMarks(String name, int mark1, int mark2, int mark3) {

        courseName = name;
        assignment1 = mark1;
        assignment2 = mark2;
        assignment3 = mark3;        
    }
}
```

Student objects are to be added to a list. My question is" does anyone know what is meant by "Remember to assign the two AssignmentMarks objects to the Student object" in the explanation I have been provided?

I understand the question just not how to do it.

Comment: It means you should "Remember to assign the two AssignmentMarks objects to the Student object"  what do you think it means?

Comment: "I understand the question just not how to do it." Then ask your teacher for more help. We're not going to write it for you - it wouldn't be in your best interest anyway. Questions on Stack Overflow must be *specific*. Saying "I don't know how to do my assignment" is not specific. As far as I can see, the task is already broken down into manageable steps. You just need to go through them one by one.

Comment: I am right at the beginning here. and I am trying my best. Like I said I understand the sentence, but how to assign the assesmentMarks object to Student object without assesmentMarks as part of the Student constructor?

Comment: I have been trying to get the information and better explanation from my tutor all day. The material is vague and this has not been covered. He will not help me. I am studying by distance otherwise I'd go and talk to him.If I can't get help here or from my tutor I'm a bit lost...some help?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create two `AssignmentMarks` instances :

- one for `englishMarks` attribute,
- one for `mathMarks` attribute.

For englishMarks :

```
this.englishMarks = new  AssignmentMarks("english", 
                         englishMark1, englishMark2, englishMark3);
```

You do the same for mathMarks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want or have to process the parameters given to the constructor of `Student` directly in this constructor. You can do that by creating new `AssignmentMarks` there and assign them to the class attributes of `Student`.
There is not that much to do, just add two lines to your `Student` class like this:

```
public class Student {

    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public AssignmentMarks mathMarks;
    public AssignmentMarks englishMarks;

    public Student(int studentID, String firstName, String lastName,
            int mathMark1, int mathMark2, int mathMark3,
            int englishMark1, int englishMark2, int englishMark3) {
        // assign the primitives and String attributes directly
        id = studentID;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        // assign the subject marks with newly created objects defined by parametrized constructor call
        mathMarks = new AssignmentMarks("maths", mathMark1, mathMark2, mathMark3);
        englishMarks = new AssignmentMarks("english", englishMark1, englishMark2, englishMark3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The two objects `AssignmentMarks mathMarks` and `AssignmentMarks englishMarks` are not assigned in the constructor and are therefore initialized with `null`. However, because they are declared as `public`, they can be assigned via the created object. That would look like this:

```
Student s = new Student(0, "Foo", "Bar", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
//Note that the arguments int mathMark1, int mathMark2, 
//int mathMark3, int englishMark1, int englishMark2, int englishMark3 will be ignored

//s.mathMarks and s.englishMarks are null here
s.mathMarks = new AssignmentMarks("Math", 4, 5, 6);
//s.mathMarks is now initialized, s.englishMarks is not initialized.
s.englishMarks= new AssignmentMarks("English", 1, 2, 3);
//Both are initialized now.
```

I hope that helped you.

Comment: That would not work !

Comment: @AliceOualouest Why not? Can you explain it?

Comment: It would not work because : mark1, mark2 and mark3 does not exist and because you don't write the argument types in a constructor call.

Comment: @AliceOualouest Good point, I have corrected the answer.

Answer (score -1):

> Creates a new Student object

```
Student student = new Student(id, firstName, lastName, mathsMark1, mathsMark2, mathsMark3, englishMark1, englishMark2, englishMark3);
```

> and two AsignmentMarks objects (for Mathematics and English)

```
AssignmentMarks mathMarks = new AssignmentMarks("Mathematics", mathsMark1, mathsMark2, mathsMark3);
AssignmentMarks englishMarks = new AssignmentMarks("English", englishMark1, englishMark2, englishMark3);
```

> Remember to assign the two AssignmentMarks objects to the Student
>   object.

```
student.mathMarks = mathMarks;
student.englishMarks = englishMarks;
```

> Finally, adds the Student to the list of students.

```
// List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
students.add(student);
```

Comment: Honestly Oleg I could kiss you! all I needed was student.mathMarks = mathMarks;
student.englishMarks = englishMarks; I had eveything else. I realize for anyone reading this it seems simple yet if you don't know and no one will explain how can you arrive at it spontaneously?